# access attributes using has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller which looks something like this:

```
class EventController < ApplicationController
  def index
    ...
    @events = Event.where(['eventdate < ?', DateTime.now]).order("eventdate")
    ...
  end
end
```

And my model defines the following relationship:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...  
  has_many :match_items, dependent: :destroy
  ...
end
```

I am now trying to access the event_items linked to the events defined in the the instance variable `@event` in my view as follows:

```
<h2>Your Events</h2>
<% @events.each do |event| %>​
  </br>​<span>​
    <%= event.eventdate.to_formatted_s(:rfc822) %> 
    <%= event.event_items.event_comment %>
​  </span>
<% end %>
```

the `event.event_items.event_comment` line throws an error: `undefined method 'event_comment' for []:ActiveRecord::Relation`

Why can't I not access `event_comment` as a method?

If I just use `event.event_items` the line doesn't display an error and shows the whole event_items array with all it's content displayed in my view.

So i thought maybe I can just access the `event_comment`as part of the array through using:

```
<%= event.event_items.event_comment[i] %> #where i is the index of event_comment in the array
```

But this then doesn't return anything in my display.

Any suggestions on how I can access the attribute `event_comment` stored in my `event_items` db table? Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: How is event_items defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting that error is because `event.event_items` returns a `ActiveRecord::Relation` and not an instance of `EventComment`.  Try using:

```
event.event_items.first.event_comment
```